# Use stringr and str_count to return the number of unique words in a string

Tags: r, stringr

Is there a way to use str_count to count unique words in a string?
I would like the simple code below to return 2 instead of 6.

```
library(tidyverse)

string <- "Z AD Banana EW Z AD Z AD X" 

str_count(string, "Z|AD")

Returns: 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to extract all the values that satisfy the pattern and then count unique values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

n_distinct(str_extract_all(string, "Z|AD")[[1]])
#[1] 2
```

This can be written in base R as :

```
length(unique(regmatches(string, gregexpr("Z|AD", string))[[1]]))
```

Comment: This works nicely with the above string. But when I try to apply it on my dataset (mutate = n_distinct(str_extract_all(string_var, pattern))[[1]]) it returns the same value for every row.

Comment: If you have column values you don't need `[[1]]`. Try `df %>% mutate(temp = str_extract_all(string, 'Z|AD'), n = map_dbl(temp, n_distinct))`

Comment: Brilliant! Why do I need to throw in map? Is it because str_extract_all returns a list?

Comment: Yes, in the example since you had only one string I used `[[1]]` but if you have multiple strings you need to use `map` or `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map_lgl(c("Z", "AD"), ~ str_detect(string, .x)) %>% sum
#[1] 2
```